# Indoor positioning in the background?

Tags: ios, core-location, ios8

I'm wondering what ability I have to use indoor positioning without an active user. I'd like to be able to grab users locations at various times in the background, not constant tracking.

They mention an example of finding your friends at the mall. Do they assume your friends are going to have their device unlocked all the time so you can see their location?

Are there other ways to trigger an active user, iBeacon or Push Notifications to be able to get a users position without making them unlock their device?

Thanks for any help explaining how this works.